# SQL retrieving 1st run data from a date range

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, qt5

I need to retrieve 1st run information from an Oracle database for a particular date range.  First run means ignoring rows where serial numbers that are run at a later time.

Note: 1 = Passed, 0 = Fail

Example of my data is:

```
SERIALNUM   TIMESTAMP_          PASSED  …{more data}
    001     2015-01-07T11:22:50     0
    002     2015-01-07T11:24:00     0
    003     2015-01-07T11:25:50     1
    001     2015-01-07T11:26:50     1
    004     2015-01-07T11:28:50     1
    005     2015-01-07T11:29:50     1
    006     2015-01-07T11:31:50     1
    002     2015-01-07T11:30:50     0
    002     2015-01-07T11:33:50     1
    007     2015-01-07T11:35:50     1
    008     2015-01-07T11:36:50     1
    0010    2015-01-07T11:39:50     1
    009     2015-01-07T11:37:50     1
```

Desired results, 10 units tested, 2 failed, 8 passed.

```
Using Excel to get my proper 1st run data I:
[step1] Delete rows outside of my date range.
[step2] Sort by SERIALNUM (1st level) TIMESTAMP_ (2nd level).
[step3] Remove Duplicate SERIALNUM.
[step4] Then count the number of passed units (1 = pass).
```

This gives me my desired results.
Changing the order gives me undesired results.

I can get the data from the database from my selected range by using:

```
SELECT SERIALNUM, TIMESTAMP_, PASSED 
FROM dbTble 
WHERE TO_DATE('01/07/2015 09:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= TIMESTAMP_ 
AND TIMESTAMP_ < TO_DATE('01/07/2015 14:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
ORDER BY SERIALNUM, TIMESTAMP_
```

It seems like I should be using subquery, but I saw a note that subquery cannot be sorted.

How can I accomplish this with SQL command?

Comment: If a `serialnum` is run at an earlier date outside your date range, do you want to exclude it? Also, FYI, subqueries can definitely be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the first run (only) of runs within the date range. If there is a run for a particular `serialnum` earlier than the minimum date of the range, it won't be excluded:

```
SELECT serialnum, timestamp_, passed FROM (
    SELECT serialnum, timestamp_, passed
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY serialnum ORDER BY timestamp_ ) AS rn
      FROM dbtable
     WHERE TO_DATE('01/07/2015 09:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= timestamp_
       AND timestamp_ < TO_DATE('01/07/2015 14:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
) WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY serialnum, timestamp_
```

The window function `ROW_NUMBER()` ranks according to earliest (use `DESC` after `timestamp_` to force latest).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Identical to what I was about to write.

Comment: This worked, thanks.
Ideally I would want to check the serial # across all date ranges, but I am concerned that this will come with a time penalty.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the order and how this works.  The 1st part that is executed is the select with the ROW_NUMBER(), which creates a virtual table with serialnum, timestamp_, passed, & a new virtual column which contains an occurrence count of the serial number.  The second part that is executed is the select with serialnum, timestamp_ & passed.  This query is pulling from the virtual table that was created in step 1.  This creates a 2nd virtual table containing the serialnum, timestamp_, & passed columns where the rn column must equal 1 and sorts by serialnum then timestamp_

Comment: @Kevin, that is correct. The above query could be adjusted to check `serialnum` across all dates simply by moving the WHERE clause from the inner query to the outer one (giving `WHERE rn = 1 AND TO_DATE(...` in the outer query.